# How to dynamically add a constraint to a model from a field class in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've created a ChoiceField to be used as a replacement for `models.CharField` with which I would like to dynamically add a constraint to the model.

```
class ChoiceField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model = apps.get_model(app_label='user', model_name='TestModel')
        constraint = models.CheckConstraint(
            name=f"{model.app_label}s_{model.model_name}s_test_test_valid",
            check=models.Q(f"test_choice__in={self.choices}")
        )
        model._meta.constraints.append(constraint)
```

or

```
class ChoiceField(models.CharField):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only)
        constraint = models.CheckConstraint(
            name=f"{cls._meta.app_label}s_{cls._meta.model_name}s_{name}_valid",
            check=models.Q(f"{name}__in={self.choices}")
        )
        cls._meta.constraints.append(constraint)
```

and I then initialize the field with:

```
ChoiceField(model_name="TestModel")...
```

However, this approach doesn't work because `apps` are not loaded yet. Is there another alternative approach that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What is the problem with the second one? this does not require to load the apps.

Comment: The second one runs on `makemigrations` but the constraint does not get registered.